# How to define histogram / date_histogram as parent of a moving average aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, histogram, moving-average

Using elastic search and java.
Not using a json or other external resource for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
SumAggregationBuilder sum = AggregationBuilders.sum("my_sum")
    .field("amount_field");

MovAvgPipelineAggregationBuilder mavg = PipelineAggregatorBuilders.movingAvg("my_mov_avg", "my_sum");

DateHistogramBuilder histo = AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("histo")
     .field("date_field")
     .subAggregation(sum)
     .subAggregation(mavg);
```

Comment: Which version of ES do you have? Pipeline aggregations are only available since ES 2.x